# Getting YouTube player object

Tags: javascript, youtube, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to code some webextension to control currently playing youtube players from browser action (just for practice). And i would like to ask if it is possible to get reference to player in injected script without knowledge about id? I would like to get some selector and then loop over all tabs and search for active players. 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: See: [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](//stackoverflow.com/q/9515704)